# How do I make a TextField multiline?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I have a string that is too long to fit into my 100px container. I want to make `TextField` automatically multiline if needed. How do I make it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `TextFieldAutoSize`.

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.multiline = true;
tf.wordWrap = true;
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.text = yourLongStringVar;
```

For more information check out the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#autoSize).

*EDIT : added wordwrap and multiline properties to maintain width*

Comment: this defines width as well. i don't want that.

Comment: if you add @Sim's settings to it, it will resize itself only at the bottom. If you don't use the autosizing your long text may not fit.

Comment: it worked perfectly. however i would like to break a string only at spaces, and not in the middle of the word. is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using TextField.multiline or .wordWrap?

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.multiline = true;
tf.wordWrap = true;
// etc..
```